Solve $\min -x_1-x_2$ such that $x_1+2x_2 = 0, \| x\|^2 \leq 125$ with KKT conditions.
Given the following problem
\begin{align*}
\min -x_1-x_2 \\
\text{s.t.} x_1+2x_2=0 \\
\| x\|² \leq 125
\end{align*}
From the equality it follows that $x_1=-2x_2$. Plugging this into the norm constraint yields $x_2^2 \leq 25$ or equivalently $-5 \leq x_2 \leq 5$. We use this again to transform the objective to $-x_1-x_2 = x_2$ and therefore we know that the optimum is given by $-5$.
I want to verify the the 2nd-order KKT conditions hold at $x^* = (10,-5)$ with $\lambda_1^* = 6/10$ and $\lambda_2^* = 1/50$.
It is easy to verify that
\begin{align*}
\nabla L(x^*, \lambda^*)= \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix} + \lambda_1^*\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 2\end{pmatrix} -2 \lambda_2^* \begin{pmatrix} x_1^* \\ x_2^* \end{pmatrix} &= 0 \\
x_1^* + 2x_2^* &= 0 \\
125 - \| x^*\|² & \geq 0 \\
\lambda_2^* &\geq 0 \\
\lambda_2^* (125-\| x^* \|^2) &=0
\end{align*}
Moreover, the active constraint gradients are $\nabla c_1(x^*) = \begin{pmatrix} 1\\2 \end{pmatrix}, \nabla c_2(x^*) = \begin{pmatrix} 20 \\ -10 \end{pmatrix}$ are linearly independent.
Now to the part that confuses me. The hessian of the Lagrangian is given by $\begin{pmatrix} -2\lambda_2 & 0 \\ 0 & -2\lambda_2 \end{pmatrix}$, which since $\lambda_2 \geq 0$ is negative semi-definite and never positive definite.
Could someone please enlighten me, where in my reasoning I am wrong?


The issue is that the definition of the Lagrangian is not unique. I defined the lagrangian as $L(x,\lambda) = f(x) + \sum \lambda_i c_i(x)$ with $c_i(x) \leq 0 \forall i \in I$, but for this summary they used $L(x,\lambda) = f(x) - \sum \lambda_i c_i(x)$ with $c_i(x) \geq 0 \forall i \in I$. This changes the signs in a way such that one ends up with a positive definite matrix as a hessian.
